# Android: database is not saving insert

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I'm hoping this is a bit of no-brainer.  I'm doing something like:

```
values.put("name", name);
m_db.insert(PHOTOS, null, values);

m_db.close();
```

afterwards, when I check (either in my code or the adb console), nothing is there?

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried insertOrThrow?

Comment: Ahh!  There are problems with my insert statemnt.  Reset your comment as an answere as how to find out the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried insertOrThrow(...)?

Answer (score 2):

i think this url will Help you
http://androidinsertdata.blogspot.com/2011/05/deals-with-database.html